# what is recommended to use with Mpeg-dash, VBR or CBR?

Tags: ffmpeg, html5-video, mpeg-dash

I need to trans code some videos to use them with Mpeg-dash, for bitrate, shroud I use variable bitrate (VBR) or constant bitrate (CBR).

which of them work better with Mpeg-dash?

Answer (score 8):

Both have advantages and disadvantages. Since `MPEG-DASH` can be used for adaptive streaming having a `CBR` can improve playback because with `VBR` you can temporarily go over the bitrate threshold and trigger a stream switch even if the average bitrate is within the limits.

With `CBR` is easier to calculate bandwidth use etc. since everything is constant.

The problem with `CBR` is that it can degrade quality for more complex scenes. The best compromise is to use what is called `Constrained VBR`, that is `VBR` constrained to maximum 110% of the nominal data rate.

[Source](http://www.streamingmedia.com/Articles/Editorial/Featured-Articles/How-to-Produce-for-Adaptive-Streaming-81020.aspx)